# php best way find next prev data in a json array in some condition

Tags: php, arrays, json

```
$data = '[{"a":"a","b":"1000"},{"a":"c","b":"256"},{"a":"a","b":"1020"},{"a":"b","b":"799"},{"a":"b","b":"805"},{"a":"c","b":"333"},{"a":"a","b":"1046"}]';
$json = json_decode($data);
$_GET['a']='c';
$_GET['b']='333';
foreach($json as $row){
   if($row->a==$_GET['a']&&$row->b==$_GET['b']){
      //current data
   } 
   //process to find the next data {"a":"a","b":"1046"}
   //prev data {"a":"b","b":"805"}
}
```

In some case like this, what is the best way to find next data and prev data? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach($json as $key=>$row) {

    if ($key > 0) {
        $previous = $json[$key-1];
    }
    if ($key+1 < count($json)) {
        $next = $json[$key+1]
    }
}
```